# What is the correct way to perform fitting (using LMFIT) for a model which contains a non vectorized function such as a definite integral?

Tags: python, curve, scipy-optimize, model-fitting, lmfit

I want to perform fitting of some data with a function which contains a definite integral and one of the integration limit is also the independent variable, as far as fitting is concerned. I would like to know specifically how can this be implemented using 'lmfit'.
Consider the following example:

```py
import numpy as np 
import scipy.optimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.integrate as integrate 
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_fit

def integrand(x,amp,xc,w):
    return amp*np.exp((-(x-xc)**2)/w)

def curve(x0,amp,xc,w):
    res = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, x0, args=(amp,xc,w)) #x0 is the independent variable here
    return res[0]

vcurve = np.vectorize(curve, excluded=set([1]))
# vectorizing the output of the function which includes the integration step

# Generating the data with noise
xdata = np.linspace(0,10,20)
ydata = vcurve(xdata,1,5,1) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(len(xdata))

def residual(params, x, data):
    amp = params['amp']
    xc = params['xc']
    w = params['w']
    model = vcurve(xdata,amp,xc,w)
    return data-model


# defining the parameters and providing the initial values
params = Parameters()
params.add('amp', value=1,vary=True) 
params.add('xc', value=5,vary=True)
params.add('w', value=1,vary=True)

out = minimize(residual, params, args=(xdata, ydata))
```

This however results in an error:

```py
---> out = minimize(residual, params, args=(xdata, ydata))
... 
...
...               
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Seems like the initial value of the parameters is not being read correctly

Using the scipy curve fit this I can make it to work as follows:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(vcurve, xdata, ydata, p0=[2,2,2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(xdata,ydata,label='Observed',ls='',marker='o')    

#Plotting the best fit
xx = np.linspace(0,10,50)
ax.plot(xx,vcurve(xx,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2]),label='Best Fit') 
ax.legend()

print(popt)
```

This gives me reasonable values of the best fit parameters.
Any suggestion on how to make this work with lmfit will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the `params` in your `residual` function and call `vcurve` with the correct arguments -- the parameter values not the parameter objects:

```
def residual(params, x, data):
    amp = params['amp'].value
    xc = params['xc'].value
    w = params['w'].value
    model = vcurve(xdata,amp,xc,w)
    return data-model
```